# USB not working on Raspberry Pi4 using Raspbian, first boot

Tags: usb, pi-4

I've just bought a new RPi4 2GB and I'm having issues connecting a keyboard to it through USB. I've used this keyboard with previous models of the Pi and it's worked fine and checked it and it's working correctly.

I've installed Raspbian Buster Lite, and when I got to type my login details it doesn't work (I'm aware that passwords don't show when typed).

My first guess was that it's underpowered, and the USB isn't working, but I plugged another keyboard in which lit up (but didn't work). Could this be a problem? I installed the GUI on it to see if I could see any indicator that it's underpowered but didn't see anything as far as the login screen on the GUI.

I've also tried the solution described in the answer here, but with no joy: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181991 ... berry-pi-4

I know there were issues with the 4GB, but can't seem to find anything on the 2GB. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything else plugged into the USB ports?  What power supply are you using?  What type of keyboard is it - most keyboards without key lights should draw next to nothing...

Comment: Nothing else plugged in. The keyboard is this one - https://www.trust.com/en/product/17603-convex-keyboard. The power supply is what I know least about. I've used a couple, but the most recent one is a Mi phone charger with a 2.0 a output. Edit - I've just read that it requires 3 amps... I'll try that

Comment: I would look to buy the official power supply - chargers have a nasty habit of dropping the voltage as current requirements climb.  Chargers and not power supplies :-) says he who had weeks of WiFi problems on a 3B till I changed to a power supply...